# New line if specific number with some string

Tags: php, do-while

I' really don't know what to spell this problem... but I will explain the result and code.

[image]

I need after 4 yes, new line and after 8 new line and after 13 new line and soon..

i'm still confusing with looping here... this is my code:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

do{

    $i++;

    if($i == 5) {
        echo "new line \n";
    }

    echo "The number is " . $i . "\n";

}

while($i <= 16);
```

Hope someone can help and tell my newbie in programming.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code here instead of referring us to an external site.

Comment: You mean new line after every 4 lines?

Comment: homework question? why not after 12 instead of 13

Comment: You are looking for the [`%` modulus operator.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    for ($n = 0; $n < 4; $n++) {
        print $i++." numbers \n";
    }
    for ($m = 0; $m < 1; $m++) {
        print "new line \n";
    }
}`

I try n test.. and found it. Thanks!

Comment: `for ($m = 0; $m < 1; $m++)` runs exactly one time, you may simply omit that loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one

```
<?php

$i = 0;

do{

   $i++;

   echo "The number is " . $i . "\n";
   // % operator returns the remaining after the division
   if($i % 4 == 0) {  
     echo "new line \n";
   }

} while($i <= 16);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland then line start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a modulus operator.

```
do{

    $i++;
    $remainder = $i % 4;

    echo "The number is " . $i . "\n";

    if( $remainder == 0) {
        echo "new line \n";
    }

}

while($i <= 16);
```